# Google cloud: Your active project does not match the quota project in your local Application

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to connect to a google cloud storage project/bucket using `gcloud config set project XXX`, and get the message:

> WARNING: Your active project does not match the quota project in your local Application Default Credentials file. This might result in unexpected quota issues.
>
> To update your Application Default Credentials quota project, use the `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project` command.
> Updated property [core/project].

What is not clear to me is:

1. Does this mean that, say, downloading data, will be accounted against the project quota, or my own quota?
2. How can I see my current "quota project"? I see that I can *set* it with `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project`, but how can I *get* it?

Comment: The `quota_project_id` is stored in a JSON file: Windows `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json`. Linux `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`. I am not aware of a CLI command to print that key/value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This does mean that the quota from the project ID on the ADC file will be used rather the one you set with the command `gcloud config set project XXX.`
2. There is available guide on how to [view and manage your project's quota.](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota/view-manage)

There is difference between the 2 commands base on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/gcloud#gcloud-credentials):

`gcloud auth login` - generates user credentials for you to authenticate and be authorized to access your Google Cloud resources and do a view or modification, depending on your roles and permissions.

`gcloud auth application-default login` - this generates user credentials specifically for local documentation.

To check if an ADC file exist in your host, you can view this directory:

`$HOME/.config/gcloud/application\_default\_credentials.json`

Either you make configuration on the file the same with your current config via `gcloud auth login` or backup and temporarily move the file, this depends on the situation on how are you using the ADC file. You can check the [available docs](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/application-default-credentials).

Comment: thanks a lot! I am wondering whether the page you link to on quota filters is the relevant one? I updated my question to make clear I am looking for a command line way to get the output of `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project`, it seems one could do `more $HOME/.config/gcloud/application\_default\_credentials.json` ? Thanks again!!

Comment: You can view your project quota via this [link](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota/view-manage#viewing_all_quota_console) by following the steps. The "set-project-quota" can be equivalent base on the project you are viewing.

Comment: `this generates user credentials specifically for local documentation.`. Credentials for local documentation?  Exactly what does THAT mean?